# Propagate Spring security Context

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, threadpoolexecutor

I am trying to use concurrent mechanism in my Spring based web application. so that I have used the below method to use thread concept to get the employee details. but I have failed with Null pointer exception due to spring context is null on threads.

I have used the below code:

```
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPool = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
            threadPool.setCorePoolSize(10);
            threadPool.initialize();

            ExecutorServiceAdapter adapter = new ExecutorServiceAdapter(threadPool);
            List<Callable<Employee>> tasks = new ArrayList<Callable<Employee>>();

            for (int i = 0; i < employeeArr.length; i++) {
                final int value = i;
                tasks.add(new Callable<Employee>() {
                    public Employee call() throws Exception {
                        return empService.getEmployeeDetails(employeeArr[value], finalFromDate);
                    }
                });
            }


            try {
                List<Future<Employee>> result = adapter.invokeAll(tasks);
                for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(result.get(i).get());
                }
            } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

In the "empService.getEmployeeDetails" method, I am referring the Spring context by using below code:

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = auth.getAuthorities();
```

But I am getting null pointer exception when accessing the spring context.

could anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 5):

You can take advantage of `org.springframework.security.task.DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor`. Try something like this:

```
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPool = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
threadPool.setCorePoolSize(10);
threadPool.initialize();

TaskExecutor taskExecutor = new DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor(threadPool);

ExecutorServiceAdapter adapter = new ExecutorServiceAdapter(taskExecutor);

...
```